# Why ubuntu is so slow on the SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I have managed to install ubuntu on a 128GB SD card (class 10) which dual boots with windows 10. However, ubuntu works like an old guy. It comes up so slowly. It tends to halt and overall very slow function. And the bigger problem is that the wifi connection disconnects every two minutes.

Does this slow function mean that it is a bad idea to install ubuntu on a SD card or it means that there is something wrong somewhere?

Here is the rw speed of the SD card:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k; rm -f /tmp/output

10240+0 records in
10240+0 records out
83886080 bytes (84 MB, 80MiB) copied, 0.219472 s, 382 MB/s
```

Comment: SD cards tend to have really low write speed (as there are supposed to be write-once-read-only devices). As Linux heavily utilizes file system to store various execution information (/proc fs etc.) it's probably can't fit in writing cap of an SD card (usually about 10mb/s at most). I think that's a point.

Comment: @ddnomad The `/proc` filesystem is not actually files-on-disk, is it? Also, SD cards are definitely for writing multiple times to, just not very fast (as you point out), and they degrade.

Comment: 382 MB/s write speed? Are you sure? I thought the fastest cards not even reach 100 MB/s. This smells like there is some caching going on. Please try with bigger `count` to verify.